# customize output vector (instead of category) for neural network in python

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to build a neural network with `TensorFlow`, `PyTorch`, `Keras` of other *ML library*.

The input is an image and the output is NOT a category but a vector of 100 elements (with a certain pattern for each image).

Each image has its own distinct pattern that is comprised of a vector of 100 elements, so when I'll get a new image I could predict its pattern.

The problem is that I can't use my own vectors as outputs, the only option I found is to give a category as an output...

Is there a way to establish my own output for each image (input) and let the neural network learn using those output vector (which has 100 elements each)?

I have tried looking for a way to provide my own output vectors by I can't find this option in any *ML library*.

Answer (score 0):

You can. It is called regression problem (in contrast to classification). Your model should just end in linear layer with required dimension and loss function could be mean squared error. 
I would recommend to check out some introduction to ML, e.g. [Andrew Ng's MOOC on coursera](https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning). It will give you general understanding on what you can or can not do with machine learning and specifically neural networks.

Comment: Thanks for answering :D !
The thing is that I don't want to find a function that can predict my output vector, I want the network itself to learn how to predict my output by tuning the weights and biases of the network, so I don't think regression is the suitable solution.

Comment: Regression problem is a problem of predicting continuous quantity (or, for instance, a vector of quantities which I assume your vector is). There is also an algorithm that is called Linear regression, but I was talking about the problem in general to which neural networks can be applied.